# VBA Microsoft Word - sequential numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have done this manually where I want to replace every instance of ZXZ with a sequential number starting from 1 all the way to the last occurrence of ZXZ in the word document.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to run a word VBA macro within a specific word document, where the VBA macro starts searching from the top of the file looking for each occurrence of ZXZ, replaces the first occurrence of ZXZ with "1" and then next occurrence with "2" sequentially until the last ZXZ found in a word document.

Example word document could contain:

element ZXZ
element ZXZ
...
element ZXZ

after running the vba word macro, I would like to end up with:

element 1
element 2
...
element 25

I've done this with this code but I would like to do "while" loop or something that finds each occurrence of ZXZ and replaces it with sequential numbers starting from "1"

```
    Sub my_prov_MDList()
'
' my_prov_MDList Macro
'
'
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdScreen, Count:=7
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ZXZ"
        .Replacement.Text = "1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ZXZ"
        .Replacement.Text = "2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    With Selection
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        If .Find.Forward = True Then
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Else
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        End If
        .Find.Execute
    End With
```

''''I basically keep repeating the above code until I get to 25, which is typically how many instances of ZXZ exist in each document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far more efficient:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "ZXZ"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    .Text = i
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi macroprod, this was very efficient and fast!  thank you so much for providing this solution and for all your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient method... but here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Function countOccurrences(someString As String) As Integer

    Dim iCount As Long

    If someString > "" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Selection
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = someString
                Do While .Execute
                    iCount = iCount + 1
                    Selection.MoveRight
                Loop
            End With
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

    countOccurrences = iCount

End Function

Sub my_prov_MDList()

    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To countOccurrences("ZXZ")

        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdScreen, count:=7
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "ZXZ"
            .Replacement.Text = CStr(counter)
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With

        Selection.Find.Execute

        With Selection
            If .Find.Forward = True Then
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            Else
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            End If

            .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

            If .Find.Forward = True Then
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            Else
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            End If

            .Find.Execute
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Just added a function to count times "ZXZ" appears so can use that as for loop limit

Comment: Ah, I see a bit of that was pulled from https://word.tips.net/T001833_Generating_a_Count_of_Word_Occurrences.html Good stuff!

Comment: Kubie, that works like a charm! thank you for your help.