# Automatic numbering with ms word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Suppos, I have a word file that contain following text:

4. This text1
5. This text2
6. This text3
7. This text4
8. This text5
9. This text6

Now, I want to automatic numbering, that result will be following:

1. This text1
2. This text2
3. This text3
4. This text4
5. This text5
6. This text6

I am use the following code, but it's doesn't work.

```
Sub DoAutoNumber()

Const S_FIND As String = "([0-9]@)[.|]"
Dim myNumber As Integer

    myNumber = 1

    Do While InStr(ActiveDocument.Content, S_FIND) > 0
        With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = S_FIND
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Font.Color = wdColorViolet
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne, ReplaceWith:="(" & myNumber & ")", _
                     Forward:=True
        End With
        myNumber = myNumber + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Would you please suggest me? 
thanks.

Comment: You need to post code that actually works to some extent, with an description of HOW it doesn't work for your purposes. The code you post doesn't even *find* anything in the sample text you provide.

Comment: >The code you post doesn't even find anything in the sample text you provide - because InStr(ActiveDocument.Content, S_FIND) will *always* be 0! You should look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989997/vba-microsoft-word-sequential-numbers/51995340#51995340

Comment: How to use wildcard in inStr function?

Comment: Thanks macropod, This is work fine for me.

Comment: What means by Application.ScreenUpdating = True?

Comment: You should read the entry on the ScreenUpdating property in the VBA help.

Comment: If I want to do this within a selected parts of whole document?

Answer (score 1):

Run this Macro (Sub CorrectNumbers), that should do the trick. Somehow I needed to do 2 loops as the forward looping didn't end, because the SearchString was always replaced by the same metrics and the loop started over and over again. This is why I have added a palceholder ($temp§)

```
Sub CorrectNumbers()

Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
Dim SearchString$
Dim SearchString2$: SearchString2 = "§temp§"
Dim myNumber%: myNumber = 1

SearchString = "([0-9]@)[.]"
    With Rng.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=SearchString, ReplaceWith:=myNumber & "§temp§.") = True
        myNumber = myNumber + 1
        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        Loop
    End With

    With Rng.Find
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=SearchString2, ReplaceWith:="", Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Replace:=wdReplaceOne) = True
        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

## before:

[image]

## after:

[image]

Comment: Why this palceholder ($temp§)?

Comment: you can comment the second loop out and see what happens. Somehow the Loop will only llok at the first row of the whole range, don't know why. so if the string "3." is replaced by "1." in the next step this will be replaced by "2.", then ".3.", then "4." and so on, because myNumber gets always +1.
This is why I put the placeholder inside, so that the find-loop does not recognize this string as the search pattern anymore and moves on to the next line of the range.

Comment: If you read the comments in this thread from before you posted, you'll see the issue was already resolved via the link I posted - and without requiring a double loop.

Comment: yes, you're right. actually, I did not see the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I tested. You can try it

```
Sub Demo()
 With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1."
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.74)
    .TabPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.74)
    .ResetOnHigher = 0
    .StartAt = 1
    .LinkedStyle = ""
End With
ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries( _
    wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:= _
    wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
End Sub
```

[image: Before]

[image: after]

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you read the comments in this thread from before you posted, you'll see the issue was already resolved via the link I posted

Comment: yes, you're right. actually, I did not see the comment.