# Find String in Word and Bold Selection

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

**CONTEXT**

I have a word document that I would like to perform checks to make sure it fits a standardized format.  The document is filled with 1 line bullet points.  I want to parse through each line and check every word that matches the word "Testing" to make sure it is bold.

**PROBLEM**

I am able to parse through each line and check if the line contains the word but am not sure how to check if only the found selection is bold.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
Sub checkWords()

Dim singleLine As Paragraph      'bullet point document so just went by each paragraph
Dim lineText As String
Dim pos As Integer

  For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    pos = InStr(singleLine, "Testing")

    If pos <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Testing InStr")
    End If


'PSEUDOCODE
'If singleLine.Range.Font.Bold <> True Then
'   Do This
'End If

Next singleLine

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original question said you wanted to "parse through each line and check every word that matches the word "Testing" to make sure it is bold". That doesn't suggest any decision-making is involved. Allowing the user to choose is more involved:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Testing"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Select
    Select Case MsgBox("Bold this instance?", vbYesNoCancel)
      Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
      Case vbNo: .Font.Bold = False
      Case vbYes: .Font.Bold = True
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

The above allows you to un-bold content that is already bold. To process only non-bold content, you might use:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Testing"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Select
    Select Case MsgBox("Bold this instance?", vbYesNoCancel)
      Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
      Case vbYes: .Font.Bold = True
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about the initial confusion!  This answer is perfect!

Comment: Is there anyway to isolate `.Find.Found` to check it's properties?  For example, `If .Font.Bold = True Then` to pre-check if it is already bolded before prompting the MsgBox?

Comment: @Yahtzee you probably could check  `If Selection.Font.Bold = True Then` right before the `select case`, but I’m not by a machine to double check

Comment: You could also add a little variable to count whether that instance was bolded so you can report that

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 That worked!  I was placing `End If` after `.Find.Execute` which was sending the program into an unresponsive state.  Small mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
Sub checkWords()
   Dim singleLine As Paragraph
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim pos As Integer

   For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      Set rng = singleLine.Range
      pos = InStr(1, rng.Text, "Testing")

      If pos <> 0 Then
         rng.Start = pos
         rng.End = pos + Len("Testing")

         If rng.Font.Bold Then
            MsgBox "This is bold"
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making this much harder than it needs to be; a simple Find/Replace would do the job, as would a Find/Replace macro:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Text = "Testing"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree and this would work but this would automatically bold the words!  I may not have been clear enough and will edit my question, but I'd like to provide a report of the found instances and let the user choose to bold or not.   Can it be applied in this context?

Comment: Something like what you used back here might work too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989997/vba-microsoft-word-sequential-numbers

Comment: @Yahtzee Unless you're running the process interactively, rather than using a 'report' that lacks context, it's difficult to see how one would know which instances to bold or not bold.